# Is OfficeOpenXML required or not

Tags: requirements

I am confused by the statement 
"EPPlus is a .NET library that reads and writes Excel files using the Office Open XML format (xlsx). EPPlus has no dependencies other than .NET. "

then the following statement:

"The first thing you do is to create an instance to the ExcelPackage class. To do that you first need to add a using directive to OfficeOpenXml namespace in the top of your file. This is the top namespace in EPPlus;
using OfficeOpenXml;"

so, should I always import OfficeOpenXml?  The datatable to spreadsheet code works fine without it...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Those two statements aren't contradictory.  EPPlus doesn't require anything other than .NET to run.  And the "OfficeOpenXml" namespace is part of EPPlus.

"ExcelPackage" is a class in the "OfficeOpenXml" namespace, so you could use a "using OfficeOpenXml" or you could fully qualify it as "OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage".